# Client side & server side at the same event (onselectedindexchanged)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this drop down list. is it possible to call a javascript function and the server side function at the same time from the onselectedindexchanged event?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpPartGroup" 
                  runat="server" 
                  Height="19px" 
                  Width="169px" 
                  AutoPostBack="True" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="drpPartGroup_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help.  I had something similar with a search form that had a couple of related DropDownLists in an UpdatePanel.  A reset button was wired to a JavaScript function which cleared all text fields, etc on the client side.  I also needed to reset the related DropDownLists so that a default value was selected for the first DropDownList and the related items were updated in the second DropDownList based on the default value.

Basically, my client-side JavaScript function reset all the fields, including the first DropDownList and then called the `.onchange()` event on the first DropDownList.

`document.getElementById('yourDropDownListClientID').onchange();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop an API on the server-side and use AJAX to communicate back with it (look into guidelines for RESTful APIs) at the same time you are firing the client-side function. JavaScript can't straight up ask the server to execute a function.

Drop down lists are a bit too dynamic for a solution like this though, I can't think of a way to do anything involving server-side communication with a select box that won't lead to terrible UX. You might want to rethink whatever you are doing entirely.